# Master/Staging Azure Sql Server DB and Switching Downtime

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

We have  a requirement where we are loading data in staging DB (Azure Sql database) from On premise using ADF/SHIR . This staging DB will be used to push data in Master DB (Another Azure Sql database) . We want to ensure while this load goes from Stage to Master using ADF no one else can access master DB ( for example any other application, managed service ) , what are the possible strategies for to accomplish this  ? We are also thinking to move Staging to Master load using ADF , please let us know if we have to take care of anything to maintain transactional integrity .

Thanks
Xslguy

Answer (score 0):

You could use an access script that removes all users (except for what is running the loads from staging to master), then at the end of the load, you could recreate users/access.

To make this as clean as possible you could actually do this dynamically and run a query to fetch all current users/permissions/roles, use that to remove roles/permissions, then at the end of the load use the same results to restore all permissions/roles etc. That is the best way I could think of.

If you are using DB roles to administer access specifically (rather than custom access grants) then you could use this query here to get your users (Minus your ADF user), and the Roles for the Users:

```
declare @DropUserSQL varchar(max) = ''
declare @CreateUserSQL varchar(max) = ''
declare @AlterRoleSQL varchar(max) = ''

select @DropUserSQL + 'DROP USER [' + name + '];'

from sys.database_principals
where type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER'
--and name not in ('YourADFName')
and name not in ('adf-ccok-opsinterop-dev-001');

select @CreateUserSQL + 'CREATE USER [' + name + '] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;'

from sys.database_principals
where type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER'
--and name not in ('YourADFName')
and name not in ('adf-ccok-opsinterop-dev-001')



select @AlterRoleSQL + 'ALTER ROLE [' + dpr.name + '] ADD MEMBER [' + dpm.name + '];'
from sys.database_role_members as drm
inner join sys.database_principals as dpr
on dpr.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id
inner join sys.database_principals as dpm
on dpm.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
where dpm.type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_USER'

--You will need to save the output of the Create User and Alter Role SQL so it will be available after the DropUserSQL, you could use an output variable, then reference that in ADF after Loads are complete, save it to a variable, a table, etc. however you choose.
print @DropUserSQL -- exec(@DropUserSQL)
print @CreateUserSQL --exec(@CreateUserSQL)
print @AlterRoleSQL --exec(@AlterRoleSQL)
```